# Operator "||" cannot be applied to operands of type 'IQueryable<Contact>'and 'Iqueryable<Contact>'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to create a search box in ASP.NET.MVC where I can search based on first name, last name, phone, address or email. I created variable where I retrieve the data from database but when I try to `return View()`, this it the error that shows. Any idea how I can resolve it cause I need to search based on all these criteria.

```
public ActionResult Search(string searching)
{
        var F_N = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.FirstName.Contains(searching));
        var L_N = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(searching));
        var P_N = db.Phones.Where(x => x.PhoneNumber.Contains(searching));
        var E_A = db.Emails.Where(x => x.EmailAddress.Contains(searching));
        var A_N = db.Addresses.Where(x => x.AddressName.Contains(searching));

        return View((F_N || L_N || P_N || E_A || A_N || searching == null).ToList());
}
```

Comment: boolean `or` (`||`) is not applicable to your type. Combine (with `||`) your conditions in `where` LINQ.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this `F_N || L_N || P_N || E_A || A_N || 
  searching==null`?

Comment: Are you trying to see if any of those are null? Then you must test each separately and combine the texts with ||

Comment: @AlexKudryashev They are in different tables in database cant combine them all in where

Comment: @Alexander To return the list if any of these criterias matches the text written in the textbox, cause the user may search by firstname lastname, phone,email,address

Comment: create a *ViewModel* with your `F_N...` as properties.